# Poor Man's Load Balancing

Tags: mysql, ajax, load-balancing

I have a mysql database with several tables. I have an input that makes ajax calls for every character.
Is there a way to load balance by distributing to other domains etc?

Estimated statistics:
~1000-2000 hits a day. Average site time per user ~30-60 secs.

Comment: Now? 0. In the future? ~1000-2000 a day, tops. Average site time ~30-60 secs.

Comment: I don't think you'll have any issues if you follow Novikov's advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off making the AJAX form set a timeout whenever a character is input so that let's say 300ms after the last character the AJAX request is made. I've done something similar to your solution in a Java SWING application and the load on the server to make a simple query was stupendous. As far as load balancing MySQL all I know is that you'll either have to give up on consistency or you'll have to deal with degraded write performance.

Comment: I also wanted to add that if this data is commonly shared between users (for example cities on a classifieds site), maybe you'll be better off caching the XML/JSON that you send to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about **[Perlbal](http://www.danga.com/perlbal/)** for load balancing, and it's free making it a good candidate for the poor.

It's **[source is hosted on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/perlbal/)**.